# Contact form e-mail integration Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi i would just like to ask some help regarding my contact form because I do not know where I will include in the code the e-mail that is going to be the receipient of the information in the contact form. Thanks in advance

```
 <center>   
 <form name='contact-form'>
<div>Name: </div>
<input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name'         size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<div>Email:</div>
<input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email'  s  ize='30' type='text' value=''/>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you done so far ?

Comment: @LeoTAbraham hi sir I would just like to put my e-mail as the recipient of the contact form. Thanks

Comment: Then change the **value** of the e-mail field to yours: <input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email'  size='30' type='text' value='my e-mail'/>

Comment: @Kai I edited my code because the code is incomplete please see it :) thanks

Comment: You would generally put the To address in the server side code that you submit the form to. You need to write that code. You can write it in JS (if, for example, you were running Node.js on your server).

Comment: What is the expected behaviour. I mean I guess you have a button that sends this form to some serverside implementation? And the form fields are the senders information? Then you need to implement mail functionality on the server. Maybe you just want to open some mailto: link with the information filled into the body? but then I donno why you have an e-mail field.... What is it you want to do really? Give more information please.

Comment: @Swippen because when I click the send button nothing happens..this is just a supposed to be a form for suggestions on my website

Comment: I believe you want some thing like php or any server side page to send form data. If so than you can put it in action="your server side page"

Comment: @Nimmi I use blogger platform :)

Comment: Do you have your php page to send email data?

Comment: @Nimmi I do not have? can you give me an example sir? my platform is Google blogger isn't it automatically sends to my gmail?

Comment: I am not much aware of google blogger except creating and posting blogs :), but this might can help you: <form name='contact-form' method="POST" action="mailto:yourgmailid"> and inside of your form <input type="submit" value="send" />

Comment: I think in your code you missing only button link, It should do the trick of submission of your code. Please put <input type="submit" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to create a php script that is run on submit of the form!

```
<form name='contact-form' id="form" method="POST" action="ENTER PHP URL HERE">
<div>Name: </div>
<input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name'       size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<div>Email:</div>
<input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email'  size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">SUBMIT</div>
```

then you create a php script to run your email!

example of php script:

```
<?php
$to = "test@someone.com";
$subject = "THIS IS THE SUBJECT LINE";
$message = '<html>
<body>
NAME-------- ' . strip_tags($_POST["name"]) . '<br>
EMAIL ADDRESS-- ' . strip_tags($_POST["email"]) . '<br>
</body>
</html>';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: from@someone,com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header("Location: http://successurlgoeshere.com");
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi sir I think this is a good solution. Can you give me an example on how to create a php script to run my e-mail? so that when the user click submit it the info that they type in will be sent on my e-mail? Thanks

Comment: No problem my friend - Would you like the email just to be simple, containing the input values?

Comment: <div onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">SUBMIT</div> Should be <input type="submit"> for better result

Comment: It depends whether you are using javascript validation before sending, like I do :) If not - then yes that is correct!

Comment: Is this okay for you @user3526375?

Comment: @user3526375 No problem at all, If there is anything else I can help you with please let me know - Please could you also vote my answer as useful ;) lol

Comment: @KM123 haha sure but I do not have enough reputation :p

Comment: @user3526375 Im sad now lol - When you get enough rep - youll have to upvote lol! :D